# Bootstrap Column Spacing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

http://primoburgers.herokuapp.com/menus/lunch

The columns on the left half of the page seem to be aligning with the items on the right side. I would like to remove the space between the sections on the left side. For example, the big space between the burgers and the Mexican food sections, and the space between the entrees and the soft drink sections. I removed the bootstrap class "row" to try to solve this already, but it did not help. I am using the col-md-6 to split the page into two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a parent structure with two columns, then add each menu group as individual row (bootstrap allows nested rows/columns).

Your structure should look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6"><!-- left parent column -->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- left menu group 1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- left menu group 2 -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"><!-- right parent column -->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- right menu group 1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- right menu group 2 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```